# Can we deduce if a filed force is atractive in some situation from the differential cross-section?

Tags: interactions, scattering-cross-section, weak-interaction

When a beam of particles is directed against a target, the particles in the beam become scattered in different directions. The differential cross-section tries to describe this scattering:

$$\frac{\mathrm d \sigma}{\mathrm d \Omega}(\theta, \phi) = \bigl|f(\theta, \phi)\bigr|^2$$

where $(r,\theta,\phi)$ is a system of spherical coordinates, corresponding $\theta =0$ to the initial direction of the particle beam. If the scattering is axially symmetric then $f(\theta, \phi) = \tilde{f}(\theta)$. In the latter case, could we know in some case whether the interaction between the target and the beam particles is attractive or repulsive?

In the simple case of Rutherford scattering, it seems that it is impossible to distinguish this character from the differential cross-section:

$$ \frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} = \left(\frac{Z_1Z_2e^2}{4E_0}\right)^2 
\frac{1}{\left(\sin{\theta/2}\right)^4} $$

---

**Deleted**: Although for the attractive case there will be no dispersion for $\theta \approx 180^\circ$, while there would be for the repulsive case.

Comment: The Rutherford cross section holds for either repulsive or attractive $1/r^{2}$ forces, as Rutherford himself noted in his analysis of alpha and beta scattering in 1911. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the last sentence, though - in an elastic scattering at 180$^{\circ}$ the 'attracted' particle still bounces straight back at you.

Comment: @JonCuster `in an elastic scattering at 180∘ the 'attracted' particle still bounces straight back at you` can you elaborate? Does this mean, for example, the annhilation term for bhabba scatter vanishes at 180?

Comment: No, that means an electron meeting a positron is not elastic scattering but mutual annihilation. In the center-of-mass frame, a cue ball bouncing off the eight ball is bouncing back.